# Can "night mode" or Flux be used in an RDP session

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

The bright white light from my work machine hurts my eyes. I'm trying to use "Night Mode" in Windows 10, or Flux. However, neither of them work, I assume because I'm in an RDP session? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Running any kind of screen modifier locally ought to also affect the remote session - but you cannot affect how the remote session transmits [all graphics settings are effectively locked out because they only affect the remote machine when accessed locally].

Comment: Wow, seems obvious now - thank you!

Comment: @Tetsujin, if you want to write up the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any display correction inside the RDP session itself, Most of the regular display properties are locked out as you're only viewing remotely.

The simplest method would be to apply any screen correction to your local machine, which would then also affect the displayed remote image.